# Why am I getting a 'Cannot convert the value to type System.Windows.Forms.Label' error when adding Label to GroupBox in Powershell GUI?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I am trying to simplify the usage of GUI in powershell for a project.

I use [System.Windows.Forms.Label] and [System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox]. I am trying to automate the creation of object and their size. Main goal is to resize parent container I add a child object. In my case, I am trying to add Label inside a GroupBox using theses functions:

```
function CreateGroupContainer ($Title){
    $GroupContainer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    $GroupContainer.text = $Title
    $GroupContainer.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (0,0)
    return $GroupContainer
}

function CreateLabel($Text){
    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($Text.Lenght \* 100),20)
    $label.Text = $Text
    return $label
}

function AddLabelToContainer{
    param(
    \[System.Windows.Forms.Label\] $Label,
    \[System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox\] $Container
    )
    $ContainerWidth = $Container.Size.Width
    if($Object.Size.Width \> $ContainerWidth) {
        $ContainerWidth = ($Object.Size.Width + 20)
    }
    $Container = ($Container.Size.Height + $Label.Size.Height + 20)
    $Container.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size ($ContainerWidth,$ContainerHeight)
    $Container.Controls.Add($Label)
    return $Container
}

The main calls are:
$LabelAutor = CreateLabel('Text')
$ContainerAutor = CreateGroupContainer('Autor')
$ContainerAutor = AddLabelToContainer($LabelAutor,$ContainerAutor)
```

It fails on the function AddLabelToContainer with error:
AddLabelToContainer : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Label'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type
"System.Windows.Forms.Label".
At C:\Users\louis.meot\Accenture\DCW - Service Offers Documents\Cloud\Azure AD Applications Audit\Dialog.ps1:60 char:42

- ... lToContainer([System.Windows.Forms.Label]($LabelAutor),$ContainerAuto ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [AddLabelToContainer], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,AddLabelToContainer

I am a newbie on Powershell and I tried everything that I understand. I tried to cast, rename and other stuff but without success...

Comment: remove the parentheses and the comma: `AddLabelToContainer($LabelAutor,$ContainerAutor)` => `AddLabelToContainer $LabelAutor $ContainerAutor` function arguments are delimited by a space in pwsh